# plupload with ASP.NET forms authenticated handler

Tags: asp.net, handler, formsauthentication, plupload

I am trying to use [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) to upload files in ASP.NET.  My upload handler ideally needs to be included in the forms authentication on my site, but it doesn't work in this case.  I can't see the request that plupload makes in firebug, and don't really understand what its doing.  Is there any way to get around this problem?

Here is my plupload initialisation code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
        runtimes: 'gears,flash,silverlight,browserplus,html5,html4',
        url: '/Handlers/UploadImage.ashx',
        filters: [
            { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png" },
            { title: "Zip files", extensions: "zip" }
        ],
        flash_swf_url: '/Scripts/plupload/plupload.flash.swf',
        silverlight_xap_url: '/Scripts/plupload/plupload.silverlight.xap'
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had flash set as the first runtime in my list, and this was what was being used.  Flash has a bug in it (http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-1044), which causes any existing cookies and authentication (digest/basic) information to be discarded when doing FileReference.upload. plupload has a flag to force flash to use URLStream instead of FileReference.upload.  Setting this to true fixes the problem I was having. :)